# Why is DynamoDb js sdk QueryCommandOutput Items field optional?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We had a discussion with a colleague about how to handle empty responses from DynamoDb queries. And usually it should be like this:

```
const item = await this.repository.getSomething(someParams)

console.log(item)

if (!item.Items.length) {
     throw new Error('Item not found')
}
```

but as per typescript aws sdk docs, QueryCommandOutput attribute Items - optional, so there's a possibility of an error "Unable to read property length of undefined". But there isn't...

[Optional param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TNop.png)

[logs of a response from database when nothing was found in query command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAvDi.png)

Does someone know why is this param optional and should we expect undefined in some cases?

Comment: I don't know why it's optional but presumably you could test `item.Items?.length`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm not overly familiar with typescript but from a DynamoDB perspective it always returns an empty response `{}` when an item does not exist.